# app.yaml is not pointing to the WSGI file properly in Django with Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have the following files structure:
[image]

And shown below, is the part of the code of my app.yaml that's pointing to the wsgi of my project:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: .*
  script: testproject.wsgi.application
```

Of course there are other files which I think is not necessary to be shown, such as the other apps. When I ran it in local, everything is working fine. But when I upload it to the cloud, it's not working and is showing a server error. In the error log, it says, "Import Error: No module named testproject"

I have been researching a lot but still no luck. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `src/`:

Change the path to the file:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

- url: .*
  script: src.testproject.wsgi.application
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. But it says, "
ImportError: No module named src"

Comment: Inside `src`, do you have an `__init__.py` file, even if it is blank?

Comment: Okay I tried that and it worked. I mean there's a new error coming out lol. Suddenly, one of my apps is not recognized. The error is "
ImportError: No module named teachers" where "teachers" is the name of the app. This "teachers" app is working fine in local. Any ideas about this one?

Comment: You should add another question, with the file structure for that app.  If this answered this question, you should accept it as correct.